# Element moves down with the height from top of window of scrollbar on draggable event

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have draggable element in container,if no scrollbar is there then draggable element works fine,but if I scroll container down then scrollbar comes into the picture, and when dragging element upside it is moving down by height of scrollbar from top of the window.

This issue is only coming in latest version of chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit),  and not on other versions.
How can I fix this issue.

Here is the code:
$("#workflow_container .dragme").draggable({
    containment: "#workflow_container",
    opacity: 1,
    zindex: 99,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    drag: function(){ updateWorkflowData($(this)); initWorkflowSystem(); },
    stop: function(){ updateWorkflowData($(this)); initWorkflowSystem(); },
    start: function(){ updateWorkflowData($(this)); initWorkflowSystem(); }
  });

even if when I am deleting code inside draggable event then also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution,

> ## workflow_container {position: 'relative"}